# Debugging 64bit Assembly in GDB

Tags: linux, debugging, assembly, gdb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm learning Asssembly on Linux (using wsl-2) and during the course we learn how both 32bit and 64bit code look like. For debugging I'm using kdbg. (I'm aware that kgdb is just a frontend for gdb). It works great for 32-bit files, however there is a problem with 64-bit files.
Kdbg shows no code.

I tried using DDD, but I can't even place a breakpoint there.
I wanted to use standard gdb, but it also does not allow me to even place a breakpoint. I assume the problem is with gdb.

I removed gdb from the system and rebuilt it from source but it didn't work. I don't have any other ideas.
Is it not possible to do this? Are there alternatives or other ways?

Comment: GDB works fine for me on x86-64 Arch GNU/Linux on bare metal for 32 or 64-bit processes; IDK what you're doing exactly.  I normally use `layout asm` / `layout next` to get TUI windows with registers and disassembly.  (NASM has had glitches in its debug metadata, and I think `gcc -g foo.S` might work for GAS source files if you did want GDB to show you source instead of disassembly, but I've never seen the point; I'd *rather* see the instructions that are really there in the machine code, especially if I used any macros or `times 4 imul eax, edx` or whatever.)

Comment: There's an asm debugging section at the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info

Comment: Also note that https://www.kdbg.org/ is a GDB front-end for KDE, but `kgdb` (https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/dev-tools/kgdb.html) is a Linux kernel debugger.  I assume you meant to type kdbg both times.

Comment: Yes, thank you. The problem was older version of NASM. I needed to install version  2.16 from the source and it works again :)